# Cannot send duplicate message using twitter API

Tags: python, tweepy

So I know that this is a known issue with tweets, but I am trying to send direct messages to users, and I get the same

```
'There was an error sending your message: Whoops! You already said that..'
```

error. Is there a workaround for this problem with direct messages ?

Comment: Try adding some space characters between the characters, like `I am sending message.` may be translated as `I am`   `sending message.`

Comment: What about personalising your message with the username you're sending it to?

Comment: Twitter doesn't allow duplicate tweet or messages. add any garbage characters at the end